# Convergent sequences in product

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Suppose that we have two infinite compact Hausdorff spaces $X$ and $Y$. Is there a non-eventually constant convergent sequence in $X\times Y$?

Comment: A sequence in $X\times Y$ is convergent if and only both projections of the sequence are convergent.

Comment: Could you explain the origin or the motivation of your question?

Comment: It seems to me that there should be a convergent sequence in $\beta N \times \beta N$.

Comment: Should $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces?

Comment: Vikrant Desai, no.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Fischer noted, $⟨x_n, y_n⟩ \to ⟨x, y⟩$ in $X × Y$ if and only if $x_n \to x$ in $X$ and $y_n \to y$ in $Y$. So if there was a nontrivial convergent sequence $\{⟨x_n, y_n⟩: n ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$ in $β\mathbb{N} × β\mathbb{N}$, then either $\{x_n: n ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$ or $\{y_n: n ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$ is a nontrivial convergent sequence in $β\mathbb{N}$, which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No if the space is not compact. For example take $\mathbb {N}\times \mathbb {N}$ with discrete topology. A sequence $\lbrace x_n \rbrace$ converges to a point x of the space if and only if exist $k\in \mathbb { N }$ such that $ x_n =x$ for each $ n> k $.